# Noob with a Lenovo Y50-70 running Ubuntu 15.10 w/ Nvidia 960m not running or even showing up

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

Title says it all, i have tried using PPA's and bumblebee and the correct Nvidia drivers but nothing works.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run these:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* primus
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proprietary Nvidia driver for your specific GPU:

```
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/352.63/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run
```

Then you just have to run the command below and it will install the Nvidia driver:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run
```